# QueryBuilder for user defined type in cassandra driver 3.0 (Java)

Tags: java, cassandra, cql, cql3

I have a schema as follows

```
CREATE TABLE location_by_name(
id uuid,
coordinates frozen<coords>,
name text,
primary key (name)
);

CREATE TYPE coords(
longitude double, 
latitude double
);
```

I am able to insert data using the prepared statement, but I couldn't make it out using the QueryBuilder API,it would be great if anyone could point me in the right direction.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
UserType coordsType = cluster.getMetadata()
     .getKeyspace("ks")
     .getUserType("coords");
UDTValue coordinates = coordsType.newValue()
    .setDouble("longitude", 2.35)
    .setDouble("latitude", 48.853);
Statement insert = QueryBuilder.insertInto("location_by_name")
    .value("id", id)
    .value("coordinates", coordinates)
    .value("name", name);
```

Comment: that's why we use Spring Data Cassandra to not deal with this brutal boilerplate